# What does setApplicationHiddenSettingAsUser mean?

Tags: android, settings, dumpsys

I did a system dump on my Galaxy A12 and in my recovered _pm_bug_info.txt file this seems to be a common theme.

Can anyone tell me what exactly this means?

I’ve tried googling the answer to this but still can’t seem to find the exact answer.

Comment: have you searched the internet? it's documented ... and it's nothing at all to do with javascript

Comment: Yup, I sure have. I can’t seem to find the answer to what it actually means.